# Link loses functionality after .appendTo is applied

Tags: jquery, html

When an 'a' link is appended into an HTML element it seems to become unresponsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/establish/Aqfrf/

**HTML**

```
<div class='tag-holder'>
  <span class='tag'><a href='#' class='tag-value'>Design</a></span>
</div>

<div class='tag-tray'>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".tag-value").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() { 
  $(this).append('<a href="#" class="tag-delete">x</a>').appendTo(".tag-tray").fadeIn("slow");      
  })
});

$(".tag-delete").click(function() {
    alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

Comment: I don't see `tag-tray` in your markup anywhere... ?

Comment: It wasn't properly indented so wasn't showing up. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".tag-delete").live("click",function() {
    alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqfrf/4/)

the reason is you are appending the element dynamically to the DOM in that you have to use `delegate` or `live`

[**DEMO with delegate**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aqfrf/5/)

[jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[jquery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.live()` instead:

```
$(".tag-value").live('click', function() { // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$(".tag-delete").click(function()...
```

with

```
$(".tag-delete").delegate('div.tag-holder','click',function()...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("<a>x</a>").attr({ "href" : "#", "class" : "tag-delete" }).appendTo(".tag-tray");
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6Ksp/2/